# Path bindings not working in VSCode when using SSH + Singularity container

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ssh, singularity-container

### The issue

I am trying to use VSCode's remote SSH editing capabilities in conjunction with a (remote) Singularity container. I am able to connect, but I cannot get the paths to forward when I set up a new SSH window inside VSCode.

### What I have tried

I have followed the steps listed [in this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72774611/use-singularity-container-as-python-interpreter-in-visual-studio-code) which has given me partial progress. Here is what my `~/.ssh/config` file looks like:

```
Host myimage1~*
  RemoteCommand singularity shell --bind /folder1,/folder2 /path/to/image.sif
  RequestTTY yes

Host somehost myimage1~somehost
  HostName <my-hostname-here>
  User <my-username-here>
```

**If I open up a terminal and execute `ssh myimage1~somehost`, the bindings are captured correctly** (checked by trying `ls /` and seeing `folder1` and `folder2`). However, when I start a new VSCode remote window using this host, the folders are not bound.

Does anyone know why the path binding only works sometimes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit unsatisfying, but I ended up deleting the folders `.vscode-container` and `.vscode-server` from my remote Singularity container and re-installing them. This fixed my issue